# Проанализировав или исходя из анализа?

Tags: стилистика, семантика

> Проанализировав практику, можно выделить основные моменты.

Корректно ли построено предложение? Если нет, то уместен ли такой вариант:

> Исходя из анализа практики, можно выделить основные моменты?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, первый вариант несколько коряв. Лучше было бы сказать "Проанализировав практику, я могу выделить основные моменты". Дело в том, что в первой части предложения речь идет о том, кто анализировал, значит, и во второй надо определить, кто именно это делал.
А вот второй вариант вполне хорош - тут вообще нет речи о конкретном человеке, который анализировал.

Comment: Деепричастный оборот вполне может употребляться в безличном инфинитивном предложении. Именно безличная конструкция позволяет выразить мысль, что не только я могу выделить основные моменты, а и любой, кто проанализирует.

Comment: Чистое имхо. Деепричастия несовершенного вида лучше сочетаются с подобныи безличными конструкциями.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, оба варианта имеют право на существование, ибо в них никакие нормы не нарушены.